# Sha1 hex of UUID - Use as access Token

Tags: go, uuid, sha1

I am writing a Go OAuth application in which I am generating a UUID and using it as an accessToken, and returning it to the customer. I don't want to save naked accessToken in DB because it is valid for a long time.. So I am generating a hash using Sha1 and saving it like below

```
import "github.com/pborman/uuid"
accessToken := uuid.NewRandom()
mac := hmac.New(sha1.New, mysecretkey)
mac.Write([]byte(accessToken)
signed := mac.Sum(nil)
accessTokenDB hex.EncodeToString(signed)
```

By using uuid as accessToken gives me very low probability of collision.  I want to know if accessTokenDB will also give same very low probability of collision or not. I am saving accessTokenDB to a column which has unique index.

Comment: A Version 4 UUID, which you are using, has 122 random bits. SHA1 produces a 160-bit hash. So, on the surface, SHA1 has a lower collision probability. But since hashing has a chance of introducing collisions, regardless of bit length, you are probably increasing the chance of collision, imperceptibly.

Comment: I'm with @Flimzy. Since the token is long lived, you're basically storing a password. There's already [best practices for that](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet), like [bcrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt), which don't require proper key management. Here's a discussion about using [HMAC to store passwords over on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/hmac-why-not-hmac-for-password-storage#3168).

Comment: Yes, use bcrypt or similar. Don't re-invent the wheel when it comes to security. You'll almost always make a mistake (I say this from experience, having made many such mistakes over the last 20 years of my software development career).

Comment: Just want to make one point here. Usecase of accesstoken is different than that of password. Using bcrypt for access token will have big impact on performance because I have to also search based on access token in redis and sometimes in db. Search is not the case with passwords. That is why I was using sha1 as it gave me 160 bit output as compared to bcrypt which is giving a 260 bit output.  I am still exploring more solutions in which first I do not need to store a naked access token, second it should not have collisions and last performance has to be good due to redis and db queries.

Comment: I agree Sha1 may not be good idea but so far it fits more better for my three requirements mentioned above. I am exploring more.

Comment: The primary factor in search time will be the number of entries in your database, not the length of entries. So 260 bits vs 160 bits will have a very negligible difference.

Answer (score 1):

For good encrypted messages or checksums, the probability of collision is almost impossible.

Good cryptographic and checksum algorithms produce encrypted messages which are indistinguishable from randomness. Anything less means something of the original message survives. That means any given access token is equally likely to map to any possible encrypted message. Anything less would allow an attacker to guess the message.

> The cryptographic strength of the HMAC depends upon the cryptographic strength of the underlying hash function, the size of its hash output, and the size and quality of the key.

While it's not exactly broken, [the security of SHA-1 has been significantly eroded](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SHA-1#/Cryptanalysis_and_validation). You'd should use SHA-256 or better.